# Java programming how to run both integer and float

Tags: java

I need help with my java homework, I have most of the code and it runs but my teacher wants to be able to enter an integer or a floating point currently it only handles an integer and gives an error when you put in a floating point

```
public class ErrorHandling {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int i1 = 0;
        while (true) {
            try {
                System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
                i1 = sc.nextInt();
                break;
            } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                System.out.println("try again");
                sc.nextLine();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("you entered: " + (i1));
    }
}
```

Comment: Please read the help sections to see how to post code, and then please try to re-post your **formatted** code.

Comment: `float` can take integers as well, so just use that instead. It doesn't work the other way, i.e. `int` can't hold a `float`

Answer (score 0):

your code should be like this:

```
public class ErrorHandling {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    float i1 = 0;
    while (true) {
        try {
            System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
            i1 = sc.nextFloat();
            break;
        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.println("try again");
            sc.nextLine();
        }
      }
      System.out.println("you entered: " + (i1));
   }
 }
```

because `float` variable can accept integer values as well.